# Import pyspark in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-lambda

I created an ETL job in AWS Glue that creates an ORC file with only one raw (that indicates if two other files have the same count of rows).

Now in my pipeline I created an AWS Lambda function to try to read that ORC file and ask if the count of rows is equal in both tables (this ORC file stored in S3 has a value column that indicates if there exists a difference in the counts or not with a 1 and a 0 respectively).

In my first attempt I was trying to use pandas but Lambda gave me the error:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named

Now I'm trying to import pyspark context like `sparksession` and use `df = spark.read.orc()`, but is giving me the same error:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyspark'

What do you think? How could I instantiate `sparksession` in my Lambda function or read the ORC file in another way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyspark'

This mean the `Lambda` can not found the depenedncy, upload a dependency zip file as a `Layer` for your `Lambda`.

How to create `Layer`?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html
Or you can add the `Layer` that built by other contributors.
https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers

Comment: Hi cookieandcoke, thanks for the repply. I was looking pandas, pyorc and pyspark arn's to upload to my lambda functions but only see pandas library in klayers, do you know where i can find this other two libraries to download? Thanks

Comment: If you can not found the PySpark dependency, you can build it by youself.  
https://aws.plainenglish.io/spark-on-aws-lambda-c65877c0ac96